# Android number input with plus and minus sign

Tags: android, android-widget

I am developing in Android and I would like an input field for numbers, where the user can select the correct number using the plus sign at the top and the minus sign at the bottom of the input field. I know this works for `DatePicker`. Is there some property or something similar to make this available for any integer number input field?

Thanks

Comment: strange that google said spinner to combobox and does not provide a nummber spinner at all ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built-in widget for doing this.  You'd have to write your own.  Here's the source for [DatePicker](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java;h=ebaf4743123c350ddf5c2b61deefbeafece94aa7;hb=HEAD) - you can use it for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks. I feared it would be that way. :)

Answer (score 9):

NumberPicker is now available in Android SDK. (Added in API level 11)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Answer (score 5):

I've just released some code that does just what you want. Check out my custom control, NumberPicker, which can be seen here: 
http://www.technologichron.net/?p=42

Answer (score 3):

The open source number picker project found here:
https://github.com/mrn/numberpicker

does precisely what is requested

Comment: Link is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/65da9820998fddc9